# How to call wsdl in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I am working on project which requires calling below web service

```
https://kra.ndml.in/sms-ws/PANServiceImplService/PANServiceImplService.wsdl
```

But i am not sure how to make web service client to call the above service.

Can anyone please explain me steps to use in eclipse to call the above web service.

Comment: You can use class `PANServiceImplProxy`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

click Next and finish  , then basic code is ready .

Comment: but first we need to create project and then we can add this web service client inside that project. so i want to confirm that first i need to create simple java project or dynamic web project.

Comment: I think they are both OK , use one according to your system requirement .